# C++: Shall I return a vector of float ? or its reference or pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I have the following function:

```
std::vector<float> myFunction(int method_enum, int num_points, float a, float b) {

    std::vector<float> weights = {};
    weights.push_back(1.0);
    if (method_enum == MyMethod::linear) {
        float dx = (1 - a*b) / float(num_points - 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < num_points; i++) {
            weights.push_back(1 - i * dx);
        }
    }
    return weights;
};
```

The above function returns a vector of float, and the code works fine. However, I am wondering to have a better coding practice, should I actually return a pointer of weights or a reference of weights? If so, how do I modify the above function?

Or maybe I should rephrase my question as: if the weights vector is large, we don't want to pass a giant vector each time, what would be a better design for such a function? (I came from Java background, collections were passed by reference automatically, and am wondering how to pass a giant array (collections) in C++?) Thanks a lot!

Comment: What would that pointer you want to return point to? what would a reference you return refer to?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: **Never** return a pointer or reference to a non static function local variable.

Comment: ^^ that being said, maybe you could pass an empty `weights` vector to the function by *reference* after having reserved a size of `num_points`. In that way, you won't return a copy of `weights` vector back from the function.

Comment: In response to the edit:  Returning a vector post C++11 is fine.  It invokes the move constructor so the cost to return it is a few pointer copies.  You'll copy `sizeof(std::vector<float>)` bytes instead of `weights.size() * sizeof(float)` bytes.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you!